PnP Core - It is not possible to change the properties of a ListItem
I am trying to change the properties of a ListItem, but this does not work or the properties are not saved.
Unfortunately, I do not receive an error message.
I have already tried to update the ListItem directly via the listItem.UpdateAsync() function and also listItem.Properties.UpdateAsync().
But unfortunately none of it worked.
listItem.Properties["myProp"] = "myValue";

Does anyone have the same problem or does anyone have an idea how I can fix this?
My code example:
using var context = await PnpContextFactory.GsCreateContextAsync(
        "https://xxxxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxxxxxxxxxx");

var list = await context.Web.GsGetListAsync("/sites/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxx");

var listItem = await list.Items.GetByIdAsync(6);
await listItem.LoadAsync(i => i.Properties);

listItem.Properties["myTestProp"] = "myTestValue";

await listItem.UpdateOverwriteVersionAsync();
await listItem.Properties.UpdateAsync();

The functions that I use to create the context and for the list are basic classes that work perfectly and are used productively in other projects.

can you share your full code

please update your  question with explaining what are you trying to do, are you using function?

@Vivek Vaibhav Shandilya
I have now added my code to the description.
I am working in an Azure Function and wanted to add a PropertyBag to a ListItem to store hidden information that the user does not need in the interface by default or should not be changed by the user.

By the way, in my example I am using a document library and not a normal list
